# AngularJs routing in single page structure [JQM-Single Page]

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs, angular-routing

Currently i am doing routing in different pages and it will fine

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
    when("/",
    {
        templateUrl: "index.html"
    }).
    when("/foodscreen",
    {
        templateUrl: "addfood.html"
    })
});
```

through this way everything is fine but now i am making application with `AngularJs` and `JQuery-Mobile` in single page structure so my question is that how i configure routing in single page structure

Single Page Structure Example

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by single page structure. As in single page app, where all of your partials are loaded into a div... or all of your content is on one page and when you click on a link it will just scroll up and down the page and send you to the content?

Comment: i updated my question and give single page example that i used

Comment: Angular and JQM contain competing technologies.  The routing modules of each conflict with one another.  If you use angular, use Twitter Bootstrap for the Mobile L&F.  If you use JQM, use handlebars or mustache for templating.  The internals of JQM pagechange will really screw up the routing of angular - I know from experience.  IF you still want to procede https://github.com/angular-widgets/angular-jqm

Comment: @Emmentaler Thanks for suggestion . you are right it really screw me up

Comment: I'm assuming you want to use angularJs routing instead of jqm? I did something similar with backbonejs. Basically you need to tell jqm not to listen to hash changes so that angularJs can handle it. If this is what you are after, let me know and I can provide you with some sample code.

Comment: You are right @bmurmistro i want to use angularJs routing but i am getting problem in it.
it will be very helpful if you give me some example

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm doing it in backbonejs. Samples are in coffee script. First you need to tell jqm to not listen for hash changes:

```
$(document).on "mobileinit", ->
  # Prevents all anchor click handling including the addition of active button state and alternate link bluring.
  $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false
  # Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
  $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
```

Sample route config in backbone:

```
routes:
  "": "home"
  "home": "home"

home: ->
  $.mobile.loading "show"
  currentView = new HomeView(
    el: "#home"
    model: new HomeModel()
  )
  # render the page... view is using underscorejs for applying templates
  currentView.render()
  # need to apply jqm styles...
  $(currentView.el).trigger('create');
  # now use jqm to change the page
  $.mobile.changePage "#" + currentView.el.id,
    reverse: false
    changeHash: false
```

The routing part is specific to backbonejs. Here is a link that does something similar http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/. I had problems when I removed the page on the pagehide event. I think the more elegant approach was to simply use the trigger('create') method to get the jqm markup back on the page. Hope this helps!